# Recursion problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$A_{n+1}=A_{n}+\frac{G(n+1)-A(n)}{n+1}$$ $$A(n)=G(1)=80$$ $$G(2)=70$$

$$G(3)=60$$
$$G(4)=70$$
$$G(5)=100$$

My question is how did following equation is formed.

$$A(2)=A(1)+\frac{G(2)-A(1)}{2}=80-10/2=75$$

I want to know how it is done.

Comment: I've added LaTeX to your post (math typesetting). You can hit the "edit" button below your post to see the code I used and learn how to do it yourself, and you can also right click on any formula you see on this site and click on "Show Math As $\to$ TeX commands" to see the code. In the mean time, did you really mean $A_{n-1}$ and not $A_{n+1}$ in the first equation? And in the same equation, did you really mean $nn+1$ and not $n+1$?

Comment: That's correct typing mistake thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are equating $A_n$ and $A(n)$, which is not normal.  Then we substitute $n=1$ in the equation, giving $$A_{n+1}=A_{n}+\frac{G(n+1)-A(n)}{nn+1}\\
A_2=A_1+\frac{G(2)-A(1)}{1\cdot 1+1}\\A_2=80+\frac{70-80}2=75$$

Comment: Thanks I was thinking some other way arround.